# Function parameters to python dictionary

Tags: python, function, dictionary, input, parameters

I'm writing a wrapper function that executes several other functions.

As a simplification for this question, imagine that there is only the wrapper function and function calc_days which returns the days between a start date and an end date. You can also pass a list of dates to either the start and the end date parameter at which point the function returns the number of days for each possible combination of start date and end date.

```
def wrapper(startd,endd):
   return calc_days(startd,endd)
```

Now I would like to give the user of the function the possibility to provide the input parameters by editing a csv-file which would something like this:

```
startd;01/01/1900
startd;01/01/1950  
endd;01/01/2000
```

So the wrapper would become something like this (using pandas to read the csv):

```
def wrapper(csv_file, startd, endd):
  if os.path.isfile(csv_file):
    input_param = pd.read_csv(csv_file, ...)
    input_dict = {i: list(v) for i,v in input_param.groupby(0)[1]}
  else:
    input_dict = {'date1': date1, 'date2': date2}
  return calc_date(input_dict['date1'], input_dict['date2'])
```

I do the groupby stuff because it will create a list in my dictionary for the start date :

```
{startdd : [01/01/1900,01/01/1950]}
```

Now my problem: in the actual setup I don't have 2 input parameter but I have around 30 input parameters. So it would like to build the dictionary dynamically with the of the input parameter (*startdd*) as the key and the contents of input parameter (*[01/01/1900,01/01/1950]*) as the value.

Is there safe way to build this dictionary dynamically aside from manually creating for each of input parameters ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand 100% but don't `**kwds` fit your bill?

Comment: Your question is not to-the-point ... its a long story

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817789/how-to-add-values-to-existing-dictionary-key-python) provides most of the information you need. You'd have to loop over the index and values to bind everything together.

```
def insertintoData(aItem, bItem, cDict):
    if not aItem in cDict:
        cDict[aItem] = [(bItem)]
    else:
        cDict[aItem].append((bItem))

input_dict = {}
for i in input_param:
    insertintoData(i[0], i[1], input_dict)
```

Your *groupby* would be handled by the if/else in the function.